# JPA @ManyToOne, with additional condition

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_code", referencedColumnName = "code")
    private Group group;

    public User () {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Is it possible somehow to specify an additional condition for the above join relation? `Group` is hierarchical and `User` should always refer to the parent group, so the additional condition would be `parent_group == NULL`. Note that `code` itself is not unique.

Here is the group:

```
@Entity
public class Group {
    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_package_code")
    private Group parent;

    public Group () {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try to to add `Hibernate's` **@Filter** annotation. I am not aware of the whole schema, but it could be:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "group_code", referencedColumnName = "code")
@Filter(name="parentGroup",condition="parent_group IS NULL") 
private Group group;
```

In case of `EclipseLink` the solution could be to have separate `ParentGroup` entity. Then you can mark it with **@AdditionalCriteria** annotation and setup the mapping with `User` and simple `Group`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a DescriptorCustomizer and add an Expression to the mapping in code,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/MappingSelectionCriteria

Answer (score 1):

The `@Filter` attribute doesn't work with single entity,
it works with collection

try like this

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = DefaultPortFloatingAddress.class)
    @JoinTable(name="JCI_PORT_FLOATING_ADDRESS",joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="FLOATING_IP_ID", referencedColumnName = "floatingip_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="PORT_FLOATING_ADDRESS_ID")})
    //@Where(clause="status='A'")
    @Filter(name="status", condition="A")
    private List<PortFloatingAddress> listPortFloatingAddress;
```